# Can't display score onto my snake game dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

Hey Guys I'm trying to display the users score onto the page every time the snake its a food. I have div with the class 'score' this div is being stored 
`const score = document.querySelector('.score');` as a global. Then inside the function that runs the game I have `//increase score
        points++;
        score.innerText = points;` which sits inside the condition that tests to see if the snake has eaten the food. Nothing displays though?

```js
//declare global variables
const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
const score = document.querySelector('.score');

//set canvas context
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

//put canvas dimensions into variables
const cvsW = canvas.width;
const cvsH = canvas.height;

//create snake unit
const unit = 16;

//create points variable 
let points = 0;

//create snake and set starting position
let snake = [{
 x : cvsW/2,
 y : cvsH/2
}]

//create food object and set its position somewhere on board
let food = {
 //Math.floor(Math.random()*cvsW + 1)---number from 1 to 784
 //Math.floor(Math.random()*cvsW/unit + 1)---number from 1 to 79
 //Math.floor(Math.random()*cvsW/unit + 1)*unit---number from 1 to 784(but it's a multiple of unit)
 //Math.floor(Math.random()*(cvsW/unit - 1)+1)*unit---same as above but -1 keeps food inside canvas
 x : Math.floor(Math.random()*(cvsW/unit - 1)+1)*unit-unit/2,
 y : Math.floor(Math.random()*(cvsH/unit - 1)+1)*unit-unit/2
}

//create a variable to store the direction of the snake
let direction;

//add event to read users input then change direction
document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
 if(e.keyCode == 37 && direction != 'right') direction = 'left';
 else if (e.keyCode == 38 && direction != 'down') direction = 'up';
 else if (e.keyCode == 39 && direction != 'left') direction = 'right';
 else if (e.keyCode == 40 && direction != 'up') direction = 'down';
})

function draw() {
 //clear canvas and redraw snake 
 ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cvsW, cvsH);
 for(let i = 0; i < snake.length; i++) {
  ctx.fillStyle = 'limegreen';
  ctx.fillRect(snake[i].x-unit/2, snake[i].y-unit/2, unit, unit);
 }
 //draw food
 ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
 ctx.fillRect(food.x-unit/2, food.y-unit/2, unit, unit);

 //grab heads position
 let headX = snake[0].x;
 let headY = snake[0].y;

 //move snake in chosen direction
 if(direction == 'left') headX -= unit;
 else if(direction == 'right') headX += unit;
 else if(direction == 'up') headY -= unit;
 else if(direction == 'down') headY += unit;

 //create new snake unit
 let newHead = {x : headX, y :headY}

 //check to see if snake has hit a wall or itself
 if(headX < 0 || headX > cvsW || headY < 0 || headY > cvsH || collision(headX, headY)) {
  clearInterval(runGame);
 }

 //check to see if snakes eaten food
 if(headX === food.x && headY === food.y) {
  //increase score
  points++;
  score.innerText = points;
  //get new food unit
  getFood();
  //create 3 new units
  for(let i = 3; i > 0; i--) {
   //add those units -without this code snake will not grow 
   snake.unshift(newHead);
  }
 } else {
  //remove tail -without this code snake will keep growing
  snake.pop();
 }
 //add new head position -without this code snake will not move
 snake.unshift(newHead);
}

let runGame = setInterval(draw, 65);

function collision(x, y) {
 for(let i = 1; i < snake.length; i++) {
  if(x == snake[i].x && y == snake[i].y) return true;
 }
 return false;
}

function getFood() {
 food = {
  x : Math.floor(Math.random()*(cvsW/unit - 1)+1)*unit-unit/2,
  y : Math.floor(Math.random()*(cvsH/unit - 1)+1)*unit-unit/2
 }
 //loop through snake to see if food generates inside snake
 for(let i = 0; i < snake.length; i++) {
  //if so call the function again
  if(food.x == snake[i].x && food.y == snake[i].y) return getFood();
 } 
 //else return new random point
 return food;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Snake</title>
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nova+Square" rel="stylesheet">
 <style>
  body {
   background-color: #333;
  }

  #canvas {
   background-color: #4d4d4d;
   display: block;
   margin: auto;
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
  }

  .score {
   width: 80px;
   height: 80px;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   color: white;
   font-family: 'Nova Square';
   font-size: 4rem;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   margin-top: 50px;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="score"></div>
 <canvas id="canvas" width="784" height="528"></canvas>
 <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's working perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Actually the div is there and showing scores too. Its just hidden behind the canvas.[image]

In the style add a `margin-top:-20px` and I think it will be visible again.

You can also change the top property in style of canvas to drag it down a notch

```js
//declare global variables
const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
const score = document.querySelector('.score');

//set canvas context
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

//put canvas dimensions into variables
const cvsW = canvas.width;
const cvsH = canvas.height;

//create snake unit
const unit = 16;

//create points variable 
let points = 0;

//create snake and set starting position
let snake = [{
 x : cvsW/2,
 y : cvsH/2
}]

//create food object and set its position somewhere on board
let food = {
 //Math.floor(Math.random()*cvsW + 1)---number from 1 to 784
 //Math.floor(Math.random()*cvsW/unit + 1)---number from 1 to 79
 //Math.floor(Math.random()*cvsW/unit + 1)*unit---number from 1 to 784(but it's a multiple of unit)
 //Math.floor(Math.random()*(cvsW/unit - 1)+1)*unit---same as above but -1 keeps food inside canvas
 x : Math.floor(Math.random()*(cvsW/unit - 1)+1)*unit-unit/2,
 y : Math.floor(Math.random()*(cvsH/unit - 1)+1)*unit-unit/2
}

//create a variable to store the direction of the snake
let direction;

//add event to read users input then change direction
document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
 if(e.keyCode == 37 && direction != 'right') direction = 'left';
 else if (e.keyCode == 38 && direction != 'down') direction = 'up';
 else if (e.keyCode == 39 && direction != 'left') direction = 'right';
 else if (e.keyCode == 40 && direction != 'up') direction = 'down';
})

function draw() {
 //clear canvas and redraw snake 
 ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cvsW, cvsH);
 for(let i = 0; i < snake.length; i++) {
  ctx.fillStyle = 'limegreen';
  ctx.fillRect(snake[i].x-unit/2, snake[i].y-unit/2, unit, unit);
 }
 //draw food
 ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
 ctx.fillRect(food.x-unit/2, food.y-unit/2, unit, unit);

 //grab heads position
 let headX = snake[0].x;
 let headY = snake[0].y;

 //move snake in chosen direction
 if(direction == 'left') headX -= unit;
 else if(direction == 'right') headX += unit;
 else if(direction == 'up') headY -= unit;
 else if(direction == 'down') headY += unit;

 //create new snake unit
 let newHead = {x : headX, y :headY}

 //check to see if snake has hit a wall or itself
 if(headX < 0 || headX > cvsW || headY < 0 || headY > cvsH || collision(headX, headY)) {
  clearInterval(runGame);
 }

 //check to see if snakes eaten food
 if(headX === food.x && headY === food.y) {
  //increase score
  points++;
  score.innerText = points;
  //get new food unit
  getFood();
  //create 3 new units
  for(let i = 3; i > 0; i--) {
   //add those units -without this code snake will not grow 
   snake.unshift(newHead);
  }
 } else {
  //remove tail -without this code snake will keep growing
  snake.pop();
 }
 //add new head position -without this code snake will not move
 snake.unshift(newHead);
}

let runGame = setInterval(draw, 65);

function collision(x, y) {
 for(let i = 1; i < snake.length; i++) {
  if(x == snake[i].x && y == snake[i].y) return true;
 }
 return false;
}

function getFood() {
 food = {
  x : Math.floor(Math.random()*(cvsW/unit - 1)+1)*unit-unit/2,
  y : Math.floor(Math.random()*(cvsH/unit - 1)+1)*unit-unit/2
 }
 //loop through snake to see if food generates inside snake
 for(let i = 0; i < snake.length; i++) {
  //if so call the function again
  if(food.x == snake[i].x && food.y == snake[i].y) return getFood();
 } 
 //else return new random point
 return food;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Snake</title>
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nova+Square" rel="stylesheet">
 <style>
  body {
   background-color: #333;
  }

  #canvas {
   background-color: #4d4d4d;
   display: block;
   margin: auto;
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   top: 40;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
  }

  .score {
   width: 80px;
   height: 80px;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   color: white;
   font-family: 'Nova Square';
   font-size: 4rem;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   margin-top: 50px;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="score"></div><br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
 <canvas id="canvas" width="784" height="528"></canvas>
 <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If it helped you please mark the answer as correct so it can help others too. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

or better you can show it in canvas , ctx.fillText("Score: "+score, x-cord, y-cord);

Comment: but won't that cover up a the snake? or any food that spawns behind it?

Comment: the score will be at say right top, programmatically you can avoid generation of any food there, covering up snake might not be that big of a deal, check this https://github.com/karkipy/duck-hunt-nes something i made to me  using fillText made it seem more better

Comment: Cool game, how'd you learn to make that? Did you watch a tutorial or did you make that yourself?

Comment: I made it myself